# How to force ejection of a DVD

Tags: optical-drive

I have a DVD I was trying to rip, and handbrake froze up when scanning it.  I tried to eject the DVD by dragging and dropping it to the trash, which trashed the icon, but didn't eject the DVD.  I then forced Handbrake to quit, but without an icon on my desktop to select, how can I eject the DVD?

Comment: Question answered at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/is-there-a-terminal-command-that-will-force-open-the-dvd-tray

Comment: Does the Disk Utility show the drive or the media? Often unmounting and ejecting there work as well.

Comment: @gosmond -yeah you are right - this should probably be marked as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Reboot the computer while holding down the mouse button - if there's no physical issue preventing ejection, the disc will be ejected.

You can of course use terminal to try to force an eject, but this requires a little knowledge of text commands and is covered here:

- [Is there a Terminal command that will force open the DVD tray?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/is-there-a-terminal-command-that-will-force-open-the-dvd-tray)

Comment: The linked question shows how to use terminal, but this is the suggested way to ensure an optical drive has the best chance to eject media without accidentally unmounting the wrong drive or the wrong filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal.

```
drutil tray eject
```

DVD ejected.

Comment: This didn't work on my MacBook Air. Also, you should be able to shorten it to `drutil eject` in most cases.